# How to pass a second parameter with quotes ("") with cmd.exe /k?

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

When doing:

```
cmd /k "C:\Python37\python.exe" D:\test a\test.py
```

it fails because of the space in the directory name. But when doing:

```
cmd /k "C:\Python37\python.exe" "D:\test a\test.py"
```

it fails too with:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

**Why? How to solve this, when still using `cmd /k`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, it has already been addressed on SO: [How do I use spaces in the Command Prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/how-do-i-use-spaces-in-the-command-prompt)

Both these solutions should work:

```
cmd /k ""C:\Python37\python.exe" "D:\test a\test.py""

cmd /k ("C:\Python37\python.exe" "D:\test a\test.py")
```

Comment: Note that the two quotation marks `""` are not an error.

Comment: I used the first option in Windows Shortcut to execute SQLCMD command to execute stored procedure with arguments. 
Second option seems to not work in Windows shortcut.